# Access google drive files via api without logging in?

Tags: api, sdk, google-drive-api

I am trying to make a webpage that can display information about documents on my google drive. For example I would like to display the titles of all my google documents on a webpage. I don't want the user to have to be logged into a google account, and I don't want to have to authorize anything (or the user to authorize anything). I just want the user to be able to see what I display - in a read only format - when they navigate to the page. The user will have no chance to edit or upload or delete anything, they can just view the info I display.

Is there a way to get files from google drive (via the API or any other way) possibly without using oauth 2.0? I've looked through the api docs and even coded up the sample apps, but all of them have a step that says, "Go to this URL, click Allow, enter the code" then you get access. These steps shouldn't be necessary. I just want to download the file and be able to manipulate it (either in memory or as a stream) then display something about it.

Also, I may misunderstand how OAuth 2.0 works so if that seems like the case, any helpful information would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to authenticate your visitors into Google, but need to authenticate yourself, so your web app can retrieve data from your personal Drive.

Get an access token and refresh token for yourself, store them and autenticate your requests. If you're using one of our client libraries, most of them refresh the access tokens once they are expired. See [Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer) for more details and [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) helps you to understand how to get these tokens.

Comment: I don't want to access anyone else's data only my data. I want to display data from my google drive to the web. The user of my website shouldn't need a google account to see the info.

How do I authorize programatically without having to hit allow access for every user that views my website?

Comment: Sorry, fixing my answer now.